# BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::series does not exist

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Quiero hacer una relación 1 to N, donde una carrera puede tener muchas series, una serie pertenece a una carrera, entonces:
Carrera model:

```
public function series(){
        return $this->hasMany(Serie::class, 'id_carrera');
    }
```

Serie model:

```
  public function carrera(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Carrera::class, 'id_carrera');
    }
```

en el controller de la carrera tengo esto:

```
 public function verSeries($id){
        $carre = Carrera::where('id', $id)->get();
        return $carre->series()->get();
    }
```

pero Postman retorna error 500:

> BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::series does not exist. in file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quítale los paréntesis, el error parece indicar que trata de leer a series como un método de la clase colección y no como una relación en si

De todos modos tu consulta seria asi:

```
Carrera::with('series')->findOrFail($id);
```

Pues no hay necesidad de filtrar primero a la carrera de forma aislada por su ID, cuando podemos hacer una carga ambiciosa de Carrera con todas sus series y en esa misma consulta filtrar a la carrera por su ID.

Comment: Gracias, perfecto!